# Why is tex4ht.sty missing?

Tags: tex4ht

I have tex4ht and make4ht installed via the tlmgr-app on my iMac. But compiling is not working (see the error message)

```
  % make4ht mwe-image.tex                          
    [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
    [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: mwe-image.tex
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
    [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
    [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?    LaTeX Error: File `tex4ht.sty' not found.
    [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    2    Emergency stop.
    [FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

I am not able to find out what happens why. Its is TeXLive2022 updated, Mac OS 13.1 updated. The problem I have: I don't know where the programs are installed: looking at `ls /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex4*` there is just `tex4ebook-epub3.4ht`, `tex4ebook.4ht`and `ex4ebook.sty` and in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex4ht` there seems to be no `tex4ht.sty` (or I overlooked it).

Comment: tex4ht.sty should be in `/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty`  (at least that's where it is on my system).

Comment: On my system (MacOS 13.2.1, MacTeX2022), the `kpsewhich` utility tells me that the file is at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty`.

Comment: @ Ulrike and Mico; this is not part of my installation. As mentioned: I installed tex4ht via tlmgr. Maybe something is broken. How to install it manually?

Comment: ok, I installed at with tlmgr in a terminal window and not as the app running on my Mac. Everything is ok now maybe a tlmgr-app problem.

Comment: I don't know what "installation with tlmgr in a terminal window" may or may not entail. For sure, I can't see a drawback to going to [TUG's MacTeX page](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) and clicking on the "MacTeX Download" link.

Comment: ok, also possible to reinstall the whole installation (I guess, that's what you mean). I will do this.